# How to create a ListView with iOS TableView Grouped Style in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want create a ListView with iOS UITableView Grouped Style, like the image below. I tried many different ways: creating a TableView custom renderer, creatin ViewCell custom renderer, creating a content view, but nothing work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only looking for only table header it can be achieved by using `TableSection` with a `Title` :

```
<TableView>
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="Keyboards">
            <EntryCell Label="Deault" Placeholder="default" />
            <EntryCell Label="Chat" Placeholder="omg brb ttyl gtg lol" Keyboard="Chat" />
            <EntryCell Label="Email" Placeholder="sales@xamarin.com" Keyboard="Email" />
            <EntryCell Label="Numberic" Placeholder="55" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <EntryCell Label="Telephone" Placeholder="+1 012 345 6789" Keyboard="Telephone" />
            <EntryCell Label="Text" Placeholder="text" Keyboard="Text" />
            <EntryCell Label="Url" Placeholder="http://developer.xamarin.com" Keyboard="Url" />
        </TableSection>.
        <TableSection Title="States &amp; Colors">
            <EntryCell Label="Colorful" Placeholder="text" LabelColor="Red" />
            <EntryCell Label="Disabled" Placeholder="text" IsEnabled="false" />
            <EntryCell Label="Colorful + Disabled" Placeholder="text" IsEnabled="false" LabelColor="Red" />
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**OR**

If you are looking for both header/footer for every section, you can listview with header and footer wrapped in a view cell inside of every table section.

Source: [Xamarin TableView Samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/TableView/TableViewSamples)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a `ListViewRenderer`, in this renderer change the native control to a new grouped style `UITableView` with the same `Source`:

```
public class MyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element != null)
        {
            var groupTable = new UITableView(Control.Frame, UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
            groupTable.Source = Control.Source;

            // Create a new UIRefreshControl for this tableView, then fire the command when it begin refreshing
            var refreshControl = new UIRefreshControl();
            groupTable.RefreshControl = refreshControl;
            refreshControl.AddTarget((sender, args) =>
            {
                ListView listView = Element;
                listView.RefreshCommand.Execute(null);
            }, UIControlEvent.ValueChanged);

            SetNativeControl(groupTable);
        }

    }
}
```

The `RefreshCommand` is defined in PCL, when the task completed we would set the property `IsRefreshing` to false to stop the refreshing. So we can capture this in renderer like:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (Element.IsRefreshing == false)
    {
        Control.RefreshControl.EndRefreshing();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this solution, but now, I have other problem: I'm using pull to refresh and, when I use this solution, the pull to refresh does not work. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @ViníciusdaCruzMaia Please see my updating.

Comment: I had to did some changes in your solution. The solution to refresher didn't worked. The solution was use PullToRefreshLayout from James Montemagno (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout). And using grouped style in renderer, the cell's background color always was gray, then I had to use ContentView inside of the ViewCell and set the background color of ContentView to white. The problem of that solution is that if I want use StyleId=disclosure in the ViewCell, the background color of disclosure indicator still gray. Sorry for english errors. My english is basic